# About the verb "To be" in the Spanish translation

Tags: translation-philosophy

Some time ago, I was reading John 4:20. And as I read, I found the verb "to be (Is)".

> 20 Our fathers worshipped in this mountain; and ye say, that in Jerusalem is the place where men ought to worship.

In the Spanish translation is translated:

> En Jerusalén es el lugar donde se debe adorar.

Well, the question is why in Spanish is written,

> "En Jerusalen **es** el lugar donde se debe adorar."

and not

> "En Jerusalen **está** el lugar donde se debe adorar.""

In Spanish, the verb "to be" is in both "Es"/"Está".

How can I see the difference?

Comment: It seems that [various Spanish translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/es/Juan%204:20) take different approaches, with some using *es*, others *está* and still others neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Estar* would be the appropriate verb if Jesus were telling her where Jerusalem (or some locale within Jerusalem) is located with respect to something else, e.g. "Jerusalem is south of here" would be "Jerusalén **está** al sur de aquí."

*Ser* would be the appropriate verb if He is describing the place itself, such as "Jerusalem's temple is holy" or "Jerusalem is an old city". In this case "Jerusalem is the place of worship."

In this context He is not telling her where Jerusalem is, but rather, that it is understood to be the place of worship. Since neither the location of Jerusalem nor anything within Jerusalem is the focus, *ser* is appropriate.

*Note that He will proceed to explain to her that Jerusalem *is not* the only appropriate place for worship...in this verse He's just pointing out what is believed, before explaining why that belief is incorrect.

Comment: Here the quoted translation seems to be saying that the place for worship is *in* Jerusalem, so I am not sure your point works

Comment: @Henry thanks, edited the post for clarity. Different translations take a different approach to how closely to follow the Greek idiom. If we take Jesus to be (a) describing a specific place within Jerusalem (like maybe the temple), agree, estar would be appropriate. But if, to use an English idiom, (b) he's saying "in Jerusalem, that's the place", ser would be appropriate. The Greek ἐστὶν ὁ τόπος appears compatible with both, though I think (b) best captures the intent of the passage.

Comment: Can you give another example?